# EF core How to passing TEntity as a parameter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I create a Senior_StudentTable class mapping my database Table

```
public class StudentTable
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}

[Table("Senior_StudentTable")]
public class Senior_StudentTable : StudentTable{ }
```

if I need to get a ID's Name,I use this

```
var name=get_MyName<Senior_StudentTable>(1);
```

and methond like this

```
 public string get_MyName<T>(int id) where T : StudentTable
    {

    using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {

        var my = context.Set<T>().Find(id);



        return my.name;

    }
   }
```

now,I create a new database table type as StudentTable,named "College_StudentTable",
I don't wanna modify my code create a new class everytime like

```
 public class College_StudentTable : StudentTable{ }
```

can I use a code like

```
if(va=="College")
myclass=College_StudentTable;
var name=get_MyName<myclass>(1);
```

and it's auto mapping my new table "College_StudentTable"?

how can I do this..thanks.

Comment: yes you can pass `College_StudentTable` as `T` to `get_MyName` like  `var name=get_MyName<College_StudentTable>(1);`

Comment: Pulling the whole entity out of the database to get only its name is very inefficient.

Comment: @GertArnold It's just a example..but thanks I got it

Comment: A more fundamental question is why you want to build all these different `StudentTable` tables. Can't you have one `StudentTable` with a type or discriminator field?

Comment: @GertArnold I know,But in my solution,different tables is more clear to DBA and high efficiency at query

Comment: But a disaster for data integrity: the database doesn't stop you from having the same student in two (or more) tables. And for lookup: you have to search in multiple tables to find one student if you don't know its type. And for application development, as you already found out. And what about tables with foreign keys referring to `StudentTable`? Are you going to multiply these FK fields likewise (and make them nullable? And ensure that only one them has a value?). I don't think any DBA will like that.